Regular point of a tropical following Mikhalkin
I am currently reading Mikhalkin's notes on tropical geometry (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601041) and having a hard time working out the details of his definitions of a regular point of a tropical rational function.
He later defines the tropical hypersurface $V(f)$ defined by a polynomial function $f$ as the set of points where the tropical quotient $1_{\mathbb T} / f$ is not regular, and this should match other sources on tropical geometry. However, I fail to see how this follows from his definition.
Notations and first definitions : $\mathbb T= (\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\},\oplus ,\odot)$ is the tropical semi-field with operations $\oplus  =\max$, $\odot = +$ and units $0_{\mathbb T} = -\infty$ and $1_{\mathbb T } = 0$. It contains $\mathbb T^* = \mathbb T \backslash\{-\infty\} = \mathbb R$.
Polynomial tropical functions are defined by the formula $f(z) = \bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb Z^n} a_j \odot z^{\odot j} = \max_{j\in \mathbb Z^n}(a_j + \langle j,z\rangle )$ where $(a_j) \in \mathbb T^{\mathbb Z^n}$ is $-\infty$ except for a finite number of values of $j$. If I am not mistaken, this is either the constant function equal to $-\infty$ or a piecewise-linear convex function $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ with integer slopes.
Tropical rational functions are defined as the tropical quotients (ie the difference) of two tropical functions. The resulting function at those points $x$ where the denominator is not $-\infty$, $f$ is then said to be finite at $x$. If I am not mistaken, those rational functions are either the constant function equal to $-\infty$ or piecewise linear functions with integer slopes (with the convexity condition droppped).

The tropical quotient of two monomials is called a $\mathbb Z$-affine function. Clearly a $\mathbb Z$-affine function is an affine-linear
function $\mathbb R^n$ with an integer slope.

I feel like I'm already missing something here : because the polynomials are defined with exponents in $\mathbb Z^n$ (ie Laurent polynomials), the quotient of two monomials should just be another monomial  ! (So this definition doesn't seem to define anything new...)
My main problem is with the following definition :

A rational function $h$ is called regular
at $x\in \mathbb T^n$ if it is finite at $x$ and there exist a $\mathbb Z$-affine function $\phi$ finite at $x$,
an open neighborhood $U\ni x$ (open in the euclidean topology) and a tropical polynomial $p : \mathbb T_n \to \mathbb T$ such that
$h(y) = p(y) \oplus \phi(y)$ for all $y\in U$ .

For points in $\mathbb R^n$, this seems to be the condition that $h$ is convex around $x$. I think this would produce a definition of hypersurfaces consistent with the rest of the litterature. But then I fail to see why we need the $\mathbb Z$-affine function $\phi$ on top of the polynomial $p$. Why isn't the definition above equivalent to :


A rational function $h$ is regular
at $x\in \mathbb T^n$ if and only if finite at $x$ and there exist a
an open neighborhood $U\ni x$ (open in the euclidean topology) and a tropical polynomial $p : \mathbb T_n \to \mathbb T$ such that
$h(y) = p(y) $ for all $y\in U$ .


Is this just a subtlety on the behavior at $-\infty$ or am I missing something else ?

The $\Bbb Z$-affine function $\phi$ allows $h$ to have an additional linear term that can adjust the slope and offset of the polynomial $p$. This usually makes it easier to describe more general piecewise-linear functions, say, the function $h(x,y)=x+\min(x,y)$ on $\Bbb T^2$.
